# Mysql conenctor, why my insert query doesn't work, but the commented one does?

Tags: python, mysql, connector

That's it. I'm using mysql-connector-python. I can run the commented part successfully. But the actual part doesn't work

```
            query = "INSERT INTO selectdif (name, score) VALUES (%s, %s)"
            value = ("Sssss", 10)
            cursor.execute(query)
            
            """sql = "INSERT INTO selectdif (name, score) VALUES (%s, %s)"
            val = [
                ('Peter', 'Lowstreet 4'),
                ('Amy', 'Apple st 652'),
                ('Hannah', 'Mountain 21'),
                ('Michael', 'Valley 345'),
                ('Sandy', 'Ocean blvd 2'),
                ('Betty', 'Green Grass 1'),
                ('Richard', 'Sky st 331'),
                ('Susan', 'One way 98'),
                ('Vicky', 'Yellow Garden 2'),
                ('Ben', 'Park Lane 38'),
                ('William', 'Central st 954'),
                ('Chuck', 'Main Road 989'),
                ('Viola', 'Sideway 1633')
                ]

            cursor.executemany(sql, val)"""
```

I'm pretty sure this is the correct way to insert base on the tutorials I see

EDIT: changing from this:

```
value = ("Sssss", 10)
cursor.execute(query)
```

to this:

```
value = ('Sssss', '10')
cursor.execute(query, value)
```

fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

While you are trying to insert multiple, please check the value of your 'score' column. Probably it should be number. In your code you are passing string. That may be the reason.